# Botón salida sesión PHP

Tags: php, session

Estoy creando un proyecto en PHP. Cree un botón de salir (el documento se encuentra en procesos/salir.php) del sistema

tiene la siguientes instrucciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    session_destroy();

    header("location:../index.php");

 ?>
```

En el HTML, cree una etiqueta con la siguiente ruta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<a href="../procesos/salir.php" style="color:white; text-decoration:none"><span class="fs-3"><i class="far fa-times-circle me-3 "></i>Salir del sitio</span></a>
```

Como pueden observar, la idea es que al dar clic en el bóton se remita al archivo "index.php", pero no sucede. Me aparece el siguiente error:

> ¡Objeto no localizado! No se ha localizado la URL solicitada en este
> servidor. La URL de la página que le ha remitido parece ser errónea o
> estar obsoleta. Por favor, informe del error al autor de esa página.
>
> Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor
> comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Error 404
> localhost

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Agradecería de su ayuda.

Comment: Seguramente es por la ruta relativa, tu petición la haces desde el sub directorio procesos, pero el index está en la raíz, usa `../` para volver un directorio atrás.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código que usas? Y también dejanos desde que archivo lo haces, donde esta situado esté y donde está situado al que quieres redirigir

Comment: Hola, Roberto, Sí, realize el la ruta ../procesos/salir.php, pero me sigue apareciendo el error. Ya por el la tensión realice ../../, pero saldría totalmente del fichero PHP. Las instrucciones que estoy ingresanto en "salida.php" son: session_start();

 session_destroy();

 header("location:../../index.php");

Comment: Creo que tu problema es la ruta del archivo desde el que haces el salir.php la ruta del archivo actual, quita la linea header(locat...) y ponla después de que haces el llamado al archivo salir.php o sea desde el archivo actual.

Comment: El `header()` lo estás haciendo antes de la etiqueta `<dockerfile`?

Comment: Hola! Podrías aclararnos un poco mejor la estructura de tus archivos y carpetas? En dónde se encuentra el index.php ?

Comment: La estructura de carpetas es la siguiente:    php[index.php, vistas[inicio.php], procesos[salida.php]]. para inicio.php contiene las instrucciones: <?php 
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
  
 ?> en la cabecera, código html, , al final del código html la siguiente instruccíón; <?php 
 }else{
  header("location:../index.php");
 }
 ?>